# Use ng-repeat to generate copies of a template and each with different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angular project, and I need to create a series of items (called element.html) in a page called elements.html. Basing myself off of what I've read in the official Angular documentation, I've come up with this:

```
.controller('elementsController, function($http, $scope, $state){

    //each element.html needs a name and an image URl.
    $scope.elements = [
        {name:'John', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Jessie', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Johanna', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Joy', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Mary', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Peter', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Sebastian', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Erika', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Patrick', image: "url_to_img"},
        {name:'Samantha', image: "url_to_img"}
      ];
})
```

This is element.html

```
<div>
    <h1> <!-- Name would go here --> </h1>
    <img src = <!-- image url would go here --> />
</div>
```

And the elements.html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="elementsController">
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
      <!-- create a new element.html for each element in $scope.elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is where I become stuck. These are my questions:

1. How can I tell the ng-controller that the template I want used for each of the elements is element.html?
2. How can i plug in the data from each element in $scope.elements to each iteration of the ng-repeat?

All I can think of doing is copying the code from element.html and pasting it into elements.html within the ng-repeat div, but this just seems like such a bad thing to do. Both elements.html and element.html are housed in the templates directory. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you questions:

1. You can instruct angular to use the template using ng-include:

`<div ng-include src="'elements.html'"></div>`

2. The context variable (element in elements) will be inherited by the included template, so you can simply reference element like so:

`<div>
      <h1>{{element.name}}</h1>
      <img src="{{element.image}}" />
    </div>`

You can find a working sample here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KCkniNJaJB2vZzLqXlCK?p=preview

Comment: Yep, this is what I want, but element.html and elements.html are both separate files within the templates directory. What you did on the plunker was just insert the code from element within the elements.html. How can I call in element.html within elements.html?

Comment: In order to make element.html include-able in elements.html, you need to add element.html to angular's template cache (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). Once that is done, you can reference it exactly as in the plunker. Manually having to manage the template cache is somewhat annoying, so if you have a build system for your application, chances are your build system framework has a plugin to automate the process for you. I normally use a gulp build system with the following plugin to automate that process: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

Answer (score 0):

in your element.html

```
<div>
    <h1>{{element.name}}</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{element.image_url}}" />
</div>
```

in elements.html

```
<div ng-controller="elementsController">
    <div ng-repeat="element in elements">
      <div ng-include="element.html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although this works, you might want to put this in a directive instead.